# Multiple invoice data extraction solution?

Tags: python, ocr, data-extraction, invoice

Iam quite new to programming and at the moment iam working for a company that needs to
setup a data extraction solution.

I have found how i can extract data for 1 invoice using tesseract together with poppler in python.
My problem here is that we could easily receive thousands of invoices but my solution can only do 1 at a time.. Which will be very time consuming.

Anyone know how i could use a ocr solution to pull data from multiple invoice using python/r or something similar.
Invoices will be in same typ of structure.

Greatful for anykind of answers :)

Tried poppler and python but only works for 1 invoice.

Comment: What OS do you use? Do you have your extraction solution in single script?
In Linux/Mac you could run you single-document script in bash for every invoice file using `for` or `find` and`xargs`. Also the final solution depends on how are your invoices incoming. Are they in files, or some storage, or emails.
On windows you can use command line too.

Comment: I use windows. How do i even do such a thing in command line :P iam quite new to all this very happen for your response.

Comment: Give more details about how your current solution works. If you have written python script, you can call it for each pdf invoice.